# Remove line under bootstrap tabbed navigation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a page using `bootstrap` latest version, and using tabbed navigation for a page. I want to know how to remove the line under the tabbed nav.

Here is my image [image]

Answer (score 8):

Just overide the default bootstrap tabbed nav styling by setting border-bottom css to 0px

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="border-bottom:0px">
  <li class="active">
     <a href="#">Home</a> 
  </li> 
  <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Practice Editor </a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `"border-bottom-0"` class to `ul` tag.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs border-bottom-0">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open bootstrap and overide `border-bottom-color: transparent;` to border-`bottom-color: #ffffff;` under class `.nav-tabs > li.active > a,.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,.nav-tabs > i.active > a:focus`